# Function to allow single post template based on custom taxonomy?

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, templates, single

I'm trying to use [Justin Tadlocks function for category specific custom post templates](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2008/12/06/creating-single-post-templates-in-wordpress), but have become stuck when trying with a custom taxonomy, as his examples only have normal categories.

Can this be edited to work with custom tax's?

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Try [this](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2008/12/06/creating-single-post-templates-in-wordpress#comment-1420554).

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is the [Wordpress Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy). Basically you can just name the template `single-{custom-post-slug}.php` and put it in the right directory.

## Update

Now that I understand what you're actually asking: I bet you could hook `{$type}_template`, which is called by `get_query_template()`. It's expecting a path to the template which has been loaded. You can filter based on `get_queried_object()` so that the correct template is used in the correct place. It's probably gonna take a bit of tinkering and a lot of `print_r()`ing on your part, but I think it's doable.

Comment: Unfortunately not :(. I know about single-{custom-post-slug}.php but i need a single post template based on custom tax, as two single pages (child/parent) of the same custom post are sharing their single.php, so need to make them individual another way.

Comment: Updated my answer...see if that fits the bill a bit better